# MySQL Differences with counts caused by joins

Tags: mysql

i have a problem in MySQL where I use the COUNT function for conditions. However, when combining this with joins, although I use grouping, the COUNT values include ALL rows, even the ones filtered out.
I'm providing a minimal working example, which however maybe does not make a practical sense or is designed smartly.
So assume I have 3 tables:

- products with fields: productId, name, active (boolean)
- teams with fields: teamId, name
- rel_production with fields: teamId, productId

So basically I have products and teams with ids and names. Products can be active (lets say that means that they are still in production or so).
And then I have a relation which team is working on which product.
To explain my problem, assume the following minimal amount of data to clarify the problem is contained inside the tables:

- products
  [image: Products]
- teams
  [image]
- rel_production
  [image]

Now the query that I want to do is, in plain english: "I want all teams that are working on exactly 2 products while atleast one product must be active."
The query in general works and is the following in mysql:

```
SELECT
teams.*,
"r_count:",
r_count.*,
COUNT(r_count.productId),
"r_active:",
r_active.*,
"p_active:",
p_active.*
FROM teams

INNER JOIN rel_production r_active ON r_active.teamId = teams.teamId
INNER JOIN products p_active ON p_active.productId = r_active.productId AND p_active.active

INNER JOIN rel_production r_count ON r_count.teamId = teams.teamId

GROUP BY teams.teamId, r_active.teamId

HAVING COUNT(r_count.productId) = 2 #4 is the problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Now them problem is with team 1. Because it is working on 2 active products, COUNT(r_count.productId) will be 4 and not 2. So my query will filter it out.
Here is the screenshot with the result without the HAVING clause:
[image]
I see why this happens, because the two inner joins on rel_production will cause 4 rows to be generated. But then they are merged always together to one using the GROUP BY. So what I need is the COUNT after the GROUP and not before.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the filtering on teams in a separate subquery, and then join to that:

```
SELECT
    t1.teamId,
    t1.name
FROM teams t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.teamId
    FROM rel_production t1
    INNER JOIN products t2
        ON t1.productId = t2.productId
    GROUP BY t1.teamId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.productId) = 2 AND SUM(t2.active) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.teamId = t2.teamId;
```

### SQLFiddle